# What's the terminology for such presentation in movie?

Tags: terminology

As in the movie, [**Malena**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0213847/), Renado's thought is presented by a film in the movie. (He was watching a film in/inside the movie, and the film revealed his thought.)

And this kind of presentation is used quite often, I'd like to know whether this has a terminology or not. And if there is such terminology, what is it.

Comment: Reminds me of *Scrubs*, and JD's daydreams. Perhaps 'vignettes' would be an appropriate term?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you mean the film in the movie is a symbol, a physical metaphor or a metaphoric representation of an abstract concept.